# UIImageView tintColor colors whole image

Tags: ios, tintcolor

I've tried changing the tintColor of a `UIImageView` inside a `UICollectionViewCell` after a tap by setting render mode of the icons to `Template Image` and then setting the color by calling

```
iconView.tintColor = .blue
```

**Problem:** This fills the whole image with the chosen color, Instead of just changing the non-transparent parts.

This method has been working for me in the past, and I'm unable to figure out the problem. I assumed that the icons might have a white background instead of a transparent one, but that's not the case. Maybe it has something to do with the `UIImageView` being inside a `UICollectionViewCell`?

Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Use it `iconView.tintColor = UIColor.blue`

Comment: once check apple documetation for that property of imageview, When tintColor is non-nil, any template images set on the image view will be colorized with that color.

Comment: can you just change iconView.backgroundColor after tap? it will change the color only of transparent parts

Comment: @SashaKozachuk I don't want to change the background color, instead I want to keep it transparent.

Comment: @JanSchlorf I am having the same exact issue, still. Can anyone provide more insight?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
imageViewHome.image = UIImage.init(named: "yourImageName")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

imageView.tintColor = .blue
```

Comment: How is this different to my solution?

Comment: No, since this is the exact same method I used. Only difference is that you set it in code, while I set it in the assets catalogue.

Answer (score -2):

The following code will color only the non transparent area.

```
yourImage.image = yourImage.image!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
yourImage.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Happy coding.